# Getting this Error While Running the Project

Tags: react-native

Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-popup-dialog/dist/type.js -> node_modules/react-native-popup-dialog/dist/components/DialogButton.js -> node_modules/react-native-popup-dialog/dist/type.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
//package.json

...{
.
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
.
.
"react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
.
.
}....

Answer (score 0):

These are generally warnings which can be muted too. But if you want to resolve this, go to that DialogButton.js file and then:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';//add this

//import react-native-popup-dialog from '/dist/type.js';//comment this
const react-native-popup-dialog = NativeModules.react-native-popup-dialog;//add this
```

If you just want to hide the warnings, you can add the following code in your App.js.

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Require cycles']); // Ignore log notification by message
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();//Ignore all log notifications
```